# SQL : Show the count of multiple tables in one screen

Tags: sql, oracle, amazon-redshift

I want to show the count of multiple tables in one query. Here are the different query I have

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Table_1;
SELECT count(*) FROM Table_2;
SELECT count(*) FROM Table_3;
```

Result

```
Table_Name      Count
Table_1          51
Table_2          75
Table_3          108
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Please TAG your RDBMS

Comment: done. I want to do it in PL SQL (Oracle) and redshift

Comment: PL/SQL is a programming language. SQL is the query language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way would be to *union* your queries:

```
SELECT 'Table_1' Table_Name, count(*) "Count" FROM Table_1
union all
SELECT 'Table_2', count(*) FROM Table_2
union all
SELECT 'Table_3', count(*) FROM Table_3;
```

Answer (score 2):

A select statement on dual with different columns having result of select count(*) of each table would do.

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   table_1) AS count1,
       (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   table_2) AS count2,
       (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   table_3) AS count3
FROM   dual;
```